# Swift create array of first letters from array of strings with no duplicates

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of strings. I want to iterate through the array and grab the first letter from each string and add it to another array but only if that letter hasn't already been added. All of the answers i've found on google are really advanced and I was looking for a simple function.

Comment: Is the array of strings in alphabetical order? Or, to put it another way, what order should the resulting array be in? Can you provide sample input / desired output?

Comment: Yes, i use testArr.sortInPlace { $0 < $1 } to reorganize the strings into alphabetical order..if i have a, and, be, bad, cow....it would put into the new array a, b, c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming here that lowercase and uppercase count as equivalent, so I collect the uppercase versions of the strings in order. My strings array is called `words` and my result array is called `arr`:

```
var arr = [String]()
var previous = ""
for aWord in words {
    let c = String(aWord.characters.prefix(1)).uppercaseString
    if c != previous {
        previous = c
        arr.append(c)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer

Comment: Minor nitpick: `c` should be converted to uppercase *before* comparing it with the previous initial, otherwise `["Aardvarks", "are", "awful" ]` will result in `["A", "A"]`.

Comment: Thx @MartinR - moved it up front

Answer (score 1):

One-liner, the `[String]` is assumed to be in `array`

```
let set = Set(array.map({String($0.prefix(1)).uppercased()}).sorted())
```

or

```
let result = Array(Set(array.map({String($0.prefix(1)).uppercased()}))).sorted()
```

---

Alternatively with `Dictionary(grouping:by:)`

```
let result = Dictionary(grouping: array, by: {String($0.prefix(1)).uppercased()}).keys.sorted()
```

Comment: And how does that eliminate the duplicates? — Oh, I see, because we reduce it to a set. But now we have no order. What if he really wants an array?

Comment: The result is a `Set`

Comment: You can use `flatMap` so you don't have to implicitly unwrap `first`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's also an alternative to check for duplicates.

```
var strings: [String] = ["apple", "acorn", "tomato", "grass", "potato", "pear"]
var results: [String] = []

for string in strings {
    guard let letter = string.lowercaseString.characters.first else { break }
    let exists = results.filter { $0.lowercaseString.characters.first == letter }.first != nil
    if !exists {
        results.append(String(letter))
    }
}
```